# how to divide a vector by 4 in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a vector list (3 6 8 2 ) and want to divide each element of the vector by 4 and return the vector

```
ex:- (div4 #(3 6 8 2))
     '#(3/4 6/4 8/4 2/4)
```

Comment: Use [`vector-map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fvector..rkt%29._vector-map%29%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [vector-map](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html?q=vector#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fvector..rkt%29._vector-map%29%29) to apply a procedure to every element of a vector, as:

```
(define (div4 vec)
  (vector-map (lambda (x) (/ x 4)) vec))
```

For example,

```
> (div4 #(4 8 12 16))
'#(1 2 3 4)
```